# unable to redirect to dynamic url present inside var in anchor tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have stored my url path in variables in the controller and I want to redirect to dynamic URLs inside variable when the user clicks on anchor tag but I am unable to do that. Kindly help me.

Below is the code that I have tried already

```
     public JsonResult SendDocumentEmail(UploadReportsViewModel vmodel)
            {
                var model = new UploadReportsViewModel();
                using (var documentBal = new UploadReportsBal())
                {
                    model = documentBal.GetUploadReportsById(vmodel.UploadReportID);

                }

              var fname=  model.FileName;
                var fpath = model.DocumentPath.Replace("~", "");

                var rmodel = new RecordsViewModel();
                using (var objbal = new RecordsBal())
                {
                    rmodel = objbal.GetRecordsById(Convert.ToInt64(model.DocumentNo), SessionWrapper.SessionUser[0].AB_MainID);
                }

                var abmodel = new AB_MainViewModel();
                using (var objbal = new AB_MainBal())
                {
                    abmodel = objbal.GetAB_MainById(Convert.ToInt64(rmodel.ClientID));
                }
                var url = Request.Url.Host;

                //"<a hre="url"> Link to Retrun of Service</a>"
                MailHelper.SendMailMessage("jyoti.tretha@spadezgroup.com","sweetjt.jyoti@gmail.com", "sweetjt.jyoti@gmail.com","Important Announcement", "Thanks for Registering your account.<br>please verify your email id by clicking the link<br><a href ='url+fpath+fname'> Link to Return of Service </a>", "", "");


                return Json(new { model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you need to use some sort of trigger to update the value. Try this and get back to me if it works out.

```
 var url = Request.Url.Host;
<a href="placeholder" onmouseover="this.href = this.href.replace('placeholder', url)" 
   target="_blank">Link to Return of Service</a>
```

Comment: I resolved issue by myself need to replace a href ='url+fpath+fname' with a href =' " + url + fpath + fname + " '